# Using PyQt5 with Tox (Python3.4 and Python3.5)

Tags: python, pyqt, tox

I set up Tox for my python project. everything is ok for the not Qt related tests, but unfortunately i'm having trouble to install pyqt with tox.

I'm using python3.4 so it's not possible to install PyQt5 from pip (i think)
But i also want to be able to test this application with python3.5 (and with python 3.5 pyqt5 is available with pip)

So, i guess that i can't just add pyqt5 in my requirements.txt because it will fail for python3.4

Eventually (maybe a hack) in my setup.py i could check the current python version and write or delete pyqt5 from requirements.txt depending on the current python version but it look dirty.

How do/would you do it ?

I also have a python3.4 virtualenv for this project which contain pyqt and all the dependencies. 
Is it possible to tell Tox to use my existing virtualenv for python3.4 and to create a new one for python3.5 ?

Here is my tox file (for python3.4 only, for python3.5, i just replace the version)

```
 [tox]
envlist = py{34}

[testenv]
basepython =
    py34: python3.4

deps =
    check-manifest
    readme_renderer
    flake8
    pytest
commands =
    py{34}: python setup.py check -m -s
    py.test tests/

[flake8]
exclude = .tox,*.egg,build,data,test
select = E,W,F
max-line-length = 99
```

Comment: Make sure to use [`pytest-xvfb`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/170#issuecomment-301019150) to avoid `InvocationError` because [`DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` are not passed through tox](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/170#issuecomment-300937035).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `requirements.txt` involved here at all. Why not simply use `py35: PyQt5` in `deps`?

For other Python versions, I wrote [a script](https://github.com/The-Compiler/qutebrowser/blob/master/scripts/link_pyqt.py) to symlink/copy the system-wide installation into the virtualenv - that might help.

Comment: The requirements.txt is in the setup.py. If i understand, i can update my tox.ini and put in the "deps" section py35 : PyQt5, and it will install pyqt5 just for python3.5 and not for the python3.4 ? so i could use your script to synlink PyQt5 to python3.4 ?